# Initialize 2dim array in java by method

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, methods, arguments

I have a method "init" which must initialize the array.

```
public void init(int Arr[][]) {

        int Arr=new int[13][13];

        for(int i=0;i<13;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<13;j++)
            {

            Arr[i][j]=0;

            }

        }

    }
```

And then there's a method "create" which must use an initialized array(by init)

```
public void create() {

//here i must call the init(int A[][]) ,for having A initialized,but it's not working
}
```

How can I call the init method from create?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the array outside the function call, then populate the array with `init`.  Java is pass-by-reference(ish) which means while you can alter the content of the array being passed in and the caller will see these changes, you cannot change where the passed variable points to.  This is a Java limitation.  Try something like this:

```
public void init(int Arr[][]) {

        for(int i=0;i<13;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<13;j++)
            {

            Arr[i][j]=0;

            }

        }

    }

public void create() {
    int Arr[][] = new int[13][13];
    init(Arr);
}
```

Edit: What you are trying to do is redundant by the way, Java will automatically initialize `int`s to 0 when the arrays are created.

Comment: Great!It works,thank you.in your code I added 2 [] after Arr.....         int Arr[][] = new int[13][13];

Comment: Nice catch, forgot to include the array declaration.